# How to access a Docker registry integrated in GitLab?

Tags: docker, gitlab, basic-authentication, docker-registry

I need to access a Docker registry activated in a GitLab project (as a “package”) from an own script.  After a successful “docker login”, I can sucessfully “docker push”.  So far, so good. My `~/.docker/config.json` contains:

```
…
"jugit-registry.fz-juelich.de": {
     "auth": "dC5icm9uZ2VyOm5vdG15cGFzc3dvcmQ="
},
…
```

“dC5icm9uZ2VyOm5vdG15cGFzc3dvcmQ=” is Base64 for “t.bronger:notmypassword”.

Now I would expect that a

```
curl -u t.bronger:notmypassword \
    https://jugit-registry.fz-juelich.de/v2/mygroup/myproject/myimage/tags/list
```

worked, but instead I get an HTTP 401 and this response body:

```
{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required",
"detail":[{"Type":"repository","Class":"","Name":"mygroup/myproject/myimage","Action":"pull"}]}]}
```

Similarly, the request fails from my script. However, this approach does work for registries that I set up with Basic Http Auth myself. What is the magic spell (an additional header?) that is needed here?

Comment: why not use [Container Registry API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html#list-registry-repository-tags) instead ?

Comment: @NicolasPepinster The API is what I meant with “Similarly, the request fails from my script”.